# 100 factorial in golang

Tags: string, go, math, bigint

I want to calculate 100 factorial in golang. Here's the code I'm using.

```
var fact big.Int
fact.MulRange(1, 100)
```

Printing output gives

`30414093201713378043612608166064768844377641568960512000000000000`

But googling 100! gives **9.332622e+157**. I figured this is probably because of the datatype I am using (or maybe not). How do I solve it? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** So I ran this code in go playground and it gave the correct answer. Is this due to a limitation on my PC? Plus when I convert it to string and iterate through it, it shows different numbers

```
str := fact.String()
for _,val := range str{
    fmt.Print(val)
}
```

Here is all the code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    var fact big.Int
    fact.MulRange(1, 100)
    fmt.Println(fact)
    n := fact.String()
    fmt.Println(n) //printing 100!
    sum := 0
    for _, i := range n {
        sum += int(i) //sum of each digits in 100!
    }
    fmt.Println(sum)
}
```

and here is what go env shows:

```
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\user\go
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\Go
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build839268890=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

and go version : go version go1.10.1 windows/amd64

Comment: Please post the exact code you ran on your computer, and what `go env` and `go version` prints. The code you posted does not print anything (and as you said, it gives correct result on the Go Playground). Aim for a [mcve].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To print a `string` value, simply pass it as-is to [`fmt.Println()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println):

```
str := fact.String()
fmt.Println(str)
```

Also note that you don't need to call its `String()` method, the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package will do that for you. But not if you just pass `fact` to it, because [`Int.String()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.String) has pointer receiver, so you have to pass a pointer to it:

```
fmt.Println(&fact)
```

Or declare and use [`*big.Int`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int) in the first place, and then you can pass `fact` simply for printing:

```
var fact = new(big.Int)
fact.MulRange(1, 100)
fmt.Println(fact)
```

Actually, since all methods of `big.Int` have pointer receivers, you should always declare and use pointers of `big.Int` to avoid surprises.

**Note:**

Your original code does not print what you want because `for range` on a string ranges over its runes (characters), and `rune` is an alias for `int32`, so the characters of the result will be printed as individual numbers without spaces between them (because you print each with a `fmt.Print()` call).

For this same reason, to calculate the sum of digits, you have to convert the runes to the numerical value of the digits they represent. For this, you may simply use `digit - '0'`:

```
str := fact.String()
sum := 0
for _, val := range str {
    sum += int(val - '0')
}
fmt.Println(sum)
```

This will print (tr it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/S33fQYNSjf4)):

```
93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000
648
```

Comment: @KshitijDhakal See edited answer. At the end I added how you can calculate the sum of digits.

Comment: @KshitijDhakal Because in each iteration `val` is one digit of the decimal string representation, but not the numerical value of the digit, but the codepoint of the character, e.g. `'0'`, `'1'` etc... To get the numerical value, we subtract the code of `'0'` from it, so `'0'` becomes `0`, `'1'` becomes `1` etc.

Comment: btw why does it gives different results while running on my pc and while running go playground?

Comment: @KshitijDhakal I don't know what you're doing on your PC. It shouldn't give different result.

Comment: Sorry again, it is giving correct answer. I must've made a typo or something.

Comment: Perfect. All already defined methods for big integers here --> https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.MulRange

Answer (score 0):

credit source : quora

you can approach it this way

[image: !=∏=1]

[image: ln(.)=ln()+ln()→ ln(!)=ln(∏=1)=∑=1(ln)]

So you can calculate the sum of the logs instead of multiplying all the numbers and then  ()  the result to get  ! .

ln(!)=!

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    fact(100)
}
func fact(n float64){
var sum float64
sum = 0
var i float64
for i= 1;i<=n;i++{
    sum = sum+math.Log(i)

}
fmt.Println(math.Exp(sum))

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/74LPoIifNZ-